# Creating a Azure release when a github release is created?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I have created the following trigger/artifact source

[image]

I was expecting that when I create a release on github, it would automatically create the same release on Azure DevOps.

But that does not seem to happen, did I do something wrong? Or is there some other way to automatically run a deploy pipeline when a release is created on github?

Comment: I also tried to add a normal GitHub source with a continuous filter using tags/* but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding a Azure CI pipeline that creates a Artifact when a tag is created.

```yaml
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

name: '$(Build.SourceBranchName)'

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: |
      **/*
      !.git/**/*
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Then I use the azure artifact as source/trigger in my release pipeline, you can also set `Release name format` to `$(Build.BuildNumber)` so that the release has the same name as the tag.